# Cant install Qt Application on Nokia device

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia

From QtCreator I chose Mobile Gui Application and did not change a line of code. I built it using simulator and it works fine. When I try to deploy it on to my device I get a warning
'Application not compatible with Phone. Continue anyway.?' Obviously the app is not working on my device.

I have installed Nokia Qt SDK 1.1 and have installed Qt 4.7.3 ( including QtMobility and QtWebKit ) which comes with the SDK on to my device.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this thread](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?223860-Qt-4.7.3-and-S60-5th-quot-not-compatible-with-phone-quot) on forum nokia solves your issue. Which device do you have?

Comment: You're right. I think its a bug too.. mine is a 5800 which is a s60 5h edition symbian ^ 1 device. Thanks